# store $username and $file variables in the $_SESSION after login

Tags: php, html, session

From **index.php** I get the values of the username and password fileds with $_POST

**index.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['username']));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

    checkUser($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
}
```

Then I store these $username and $password variables inside the $_SESSION and call a function checkUser($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'])); which sends two parameters. The checkUser() function executes inside **lib.php**

**lib.php**

```
session_start();

function checkUser($username, $password){
    include "connection.php";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'") or die("No result".mysqli_error());

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $logic = false;

    if (($row['username'] == $username) && ($row['password'] == $password)) {

        $logic = true;

        echo "HI,".$username; 
?>

  <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>

<?php

            $file = $row['file'];
            echo "<img src='images/users/".$file."' >";
}
    else{
        echo "Failed to login. Username or password is incorrect. Try again.";
    }
}
```

This part is for showing the name of the user and the image according to it.

> logout.php works

**logout.php**

```
unset($_SESSION["username"]);
unset($_SESSION["password"]);
unset($_SESSION["file"]);
header("Location: index.php");

session_destroy();
```

**The problem is when I navigate from one page to another, the $_SESSION variable becomes empty. Something is wrong with session. Please help me.**

Comment: Maybe any issues with file permissions (Session Data not beeing saved) or Cookie issues (Maybe content output before the session start, blocking the header or an incorrect server clock)

Comment: Make sure you have added `session_start();`  at the top of the page, where you are getting session variables as blank.

Comment: It's extremely messy to start sessions inside library includes. Furthermore, please rethink your current approach. Why store users that are not validated yet and then rely in getting them successfully removed? Why not validate *first*?

Comment: You store passwords in plain-text ?

Comment: Check session file and see if is stored, add `session_start();` to top of every page.
Don't use `mysql_` use `mysqli_` or `PDO`, and also use it with prepared statements.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You are doing `include "connection.php";` twice in one function????? Will cause a very confused connection, or at a minimum waste a lot of connections which take quite a while to make

Comment: Do you include lib.php to the rest of your files?

Comment: The validation is already checked.

Comment: In fact you are doing `include "connection.php";` **all over the place.** Which just leads us to believe all the rest of your code is as badly designed. **Without seeing a lot more of the code we cannot do anything other than make guesses**

Comment: your code is very messy.

Comment: @RiggsFolly with `echo "Hi, ".$username; ` its also wide open to XSS and CSRF

Comment: And what is `session.start()` that does not look like valid PHP

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

in the php pages you need to access session variable add `session_start()` after the starting `<?php` code

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by navigating to other page? means how are you doing that?

Comment: And what is `session.start()` that does not look like valid PHP code

Comment: By saying navigation I mean that when I am inside the Home page and if I have logged in there the $_SESSION stays, but when I go to eg. Contact page, the $_SESSION is empty. The url of Home page is `Project/index.php?page=1`, Contact page is `Project/index.php?page=2`

Comment: did you use session_start() or session.start()?? session.start() is not valid bro, try checking it and replace it with 'underscore(_)'

Comment: I have written `session_start();` sorry for my previous comment.

Comment: change the url to confirm that you have a browser problem like for home page- index.php and for contact- contact.php

Comment: Both Home and Contact pages works inside index.php. The data is taken from the database.

Comment: i know that bro. i am asking it just to see if your browser is working or not, just change for the time being and check, later you can change it